# ASP.NET MVC URL Routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, maproute, actionmethod

i have defined a route as below:

```
context.MapRoute("SearchEngineWebSearch", "search/web/{query}/{index}/{size}",
                            new
                            {
                                controller = "search",
                                action = "web",
                                query = "",
                                index = 0,
                                size = 5
                            });
```

and action method to handle request match with that:

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Web(string query = "", int index = 0, int size = 5)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            return RedirectToRoute("SearchEngineBasicSearch");
        var search = new Search();
        var results = search.PerformSearch(query, index, size);
        ViewData["Query"] = query;
        if (results != null && results.Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewData["Results"]= results;
            return View("Web");
        }
        else return View("Not-Found");
    }
```

and form to sent parameter to action method:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Web", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
       { %>
    <input name="query" type="text" value="<%: ViewData["Query"]%>" class="search-field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search-button" />
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="2" />
    <%} %>
```

now after click on submit and sending value to action method all route values updated but url values still is equals to first time of sending parameter. for example if i sent for first time request such as http://localhost/search/web/google and for next time  http://localhost/search/web/yahoo, query parameter which passed to action method is yahoo but url after postback is  http://localhost/search/web/google still!

can anybody help me plz? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
return RedirectToAction("Web", 
   new { query = query, index = index, size = size});
```

instead of `return View("Web");`.

Also, note that you should perform a GET instead of a POST. And the index and size parameters may be ommitted if they were submitted with the default values.

Comment: sorry, because this cause unlimited redirection! and also if i change form-method from post to get, then it generate url which parameters passed as querystring and i won't that ;)